# Problems with apt-get upgrade on Debian (404 Not Found)

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dependencies

I can't update my Debian Sid system.

on running the apt-get upgrade I am getting:

```
maciej@wladyslawa:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-keyring libglx-nvidia-alternatives
The following packages will be upgraded:
  antlr apt-listchanges bluez ca-certificates-java cron dbus dbus-x11 debianutils
  dictionaries-common grep grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer0.10-packagekit
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao inkscape iso-codes libantlr-java libantlr-java-gcj libatlas3gf-base
  libbluetooth3 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbus-glib-1-dev libdjvulibre-text
  libdjvulibre21 libgc1c2 libgck0 libgcr-3-0 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgnome-keyring0 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib2 libnm-util1
  libogre-dev libogremain-1.7.1 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-gnome-keyring libpipeline1 libsrtp0
  mesa-common-dev module-init-tools network-manager network-manager-dev ogre-tools openjdk-6-jdk
  openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib packagekit packagekit-backend-aptcc
  python-glade2 python-gtk2 python-gtksourceview2 python-openssl python-packagekit rsyslog
  x11proto-resource-dev xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-dev
68 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,571 kB/121 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,249 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid/main gstreamer0.10-packagekit i386 0.6.14-2
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid/main packagekit-backend-aptcc i386 0.6.14-2
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid/main packagekit i386 0.6.14-2
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid/main python-packagekit all 0.6.14-2
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid/main libpackagekit-glib2-14 i386 0.6.14-2
  404  Not Found
Err http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid/main libsrtp0 i386 1.4.4+20100615~dfsg-1
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/p/packagekit/gstreamer0.10-packagekit_0.6.14-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/p/packagekit/packagekit-backend-aptcc_0.6.14-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/p/packagekit/packagekit_0.6.14-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/p/packagekit/python-packagekit_0.6.14-2_all.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/p/packagekit/libpackagekit-glib2-14_0.6.14-2_i386.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/s/srtp/libsrtp0_1.4.4+20100615~dfsg-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I did try both 
`apt-get update --fix-missing` and `apt-get install -f`
but that didn't help much.

Here is my source.list file:

```
deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

Does anybody have any idea how can I sort it out?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mirror is in an inconsistent state: it has packagekit 0.6.14-2 in the [package index](http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2), but the [file pool](http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/pool/main/p/packagekit/) only has an earlier version.

The situation will resolve itself naturally, when the mirror gets its next update. (Most mirrors are updated daily.) In the meantime, you can use another mirror.

If this happens often (or at all), it may indicate that the mirror is not set up properly — there are [instructions for setting up a mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror), and they're supposed to minimize the window of time when a mirror is in an inconsistent state. Please note that this paragraph is pure speculation, I don't actually know whether the mirror is misconfigured or this is just unavoidable bad luck.